# OpenSSL ciphers command

Tags: openssl

I just started learning Openssl, just want to know to understand the output of the command

openssl ciphers -v 'TLSv1.2:kRSA:!eNULL:!aNULL'

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
DH-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
....
```

Correct me if I am wrong
Au - means the authentication
Enc - Encryption cipher
What are the Kx, Mac?

Could you please help me in understanding this output?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/visual-cobol/VC40/CSWin/GUID-83ECF29B-C2D7-4A60-A9B0-A72D017E8AF4.html

```
Cipher Suite Name (OpenSSL)     Key Exchange        Encryption  Bits
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA            ECDH 256            AES         256
```

where `sha` is hash function and `rsa` is form key is shipped in